# SQL Query to get the Sum of all column values in the last row of a resultset along with row sum (group by)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can someone please help me to write a query to obtain the TCS and TRS?

```
ID  Jan Feb Mar TRS
1   4   5   6   15
2   5   5   5   15
3   1   1   1   3
TCS 10  11  12
```

Both TCS (Total Column Sum) and TRS (Total Row Sum) are new column and row respectively which gives their.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `WITH ROLLUP`, like this:

```
SELECT
    id
,   SUM(jan) as jan
,   SUM(feb) as feb
,   SUM(mar) as mar
,   SUM(jan+feb+mar) as TRS
FROM test
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
```

[Live demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae5db/6)

Comment: Thanks.
Can you please let me know how to use the aliases correctly to get the sum? The above works when both column name and alias are same. I have constraint to use ONLY alias.

Comment: @ary It does not matter if columns and aliases are different - you could replace `SUM(jan) as jan` with `SUM(something_else) as jan`.

Comment: Sorry to bug you on this again. Below code is failing when I use aliases to get the sum.

Invalid column name 'jan1'.: SELECT id , SUM(jan) as jan1 , SUM(feb) as feb1 , SUM(mar) as mar1 , SUM(jan1+feb1+mar1) as TRS FROM test GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP

SELECT
    id
,   SUM(jan) as jan1
,   SUM(feb) as feb1
,   SUM(mar) as mar1
,   SUM(jan1+feb1+mar1) as TRS
FROM test
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP

Comment: If I could vote this multiple times I would gladly do so, but really Thanks for this @dasblinkenlight!

Answer (score 3):

This query will do the job

```
select cast(id as varchar(20)), Jan, Feb, Mar , Jan + Feb + Mar as TRS
from table1

union all

select 'TCS' as id, SUM(Jan) Jan, SUM(Feb) Feb, SUM(Mar) Mar, null as TRS
from table1
```

The first column will be returned as `varchar` as this way you have a mix of integers (id) and the text `TCS`.

Answer (score 1):

select Sum(Jan + Feb + Mar) As TRS