# Do ORDER BY by excluding ROLLUP row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A follow up questions based on [SQL Query to get the Sum of all column values in the last row of a resultset along with row sum (group by)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062270/sql-query-to-get-the-sum-of-all-column-values-in-the-last-row-of-a-resultset-alo).

I have obtained the Grand Total using ROLLUP but unable to do ORDER BY on the aggregate column as it considering the Grand Total (Row TCS in the other thread). Is it possible to exclude the ROLLUP row to do ORDER BY?

Answer (score 4):

If in that column your ID is 'TCS'

you can do:

```
ORDER BY id='TCS',OTHER_COLUMN_TO_ORDER_BY
```

the first part will evaluate to 0 on every row that isn't the last and to 1 in the last. Since 0 comes first, the results will appear on top and this row at the bottom.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c3ed/10)</kbd>