# How to Merge rows with same value in rdlc?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc

I tried to create report using rdlc in Visual Studio 2010, but it gives this report:

```
+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|     EmpName     |   Date    | Und Vale | BROM-001 | BROM-002 | BROM-003 | Total Vale |
+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| Abelligos ,Alex | 3/13/2014 | 0.00     | 100.00   | 0.00     | 0.00     | 400.00     |
| Abelligos ,Alex | 3/13/2014 | 0.00     | 0.00     | 0.00     | 200.00   | 400.00     |
| Abelligos ,Alex | 3/13/2014 | 0.00     | 0.00     | 100.00   | 0.00     | 400.00     |
+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

All I want is:

```
+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|     EmpName     |   Date    | Und Vale | BROM-001 | BROM-002 | BROM-003 | Total Vale |
+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| Abelligos ,Alex | 3/13/2014 | 0.00     | 100.00   | 100.00   | 200.00   | 400.00     |
+-----------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Any help?

Comment: have you tried to add a group? or better do do a group by on the query?

Comment: hi Raphael! actually i tried but cant get better format as shown, can you help me!, by the way thank your reply

Comment: Hi xrompe, I would approach you problem from the query, grouping it by EmpName (and maybe Date), using a sum or max clause for the other field.

Comment: Hi! Yes it works but one thing more i cant merge those brom-001 ... brom-003, do you have any suggestion again.

Comment: To get the total column? if so you have 2 ways the first is to do it on the query see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062270/sql-query-to-get-the-sum-of-all-column-values-in-the-last-row-of-a-resultset-alo, otherwise you can do it on the report, adding a column to the table that uses an expression that sums the other columns

Comment: I tried to group emp and date, but 3 rows appear, all i want is to get one row only in every emp. thanks again.

Comment: The just group by emp and get the max(date), Sum(Brom...), Sum(brom1+brom2+...). This should work

Comment: in sql but how about in rdlc,?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem you should do a row grouping just on the EmpName, them get the max(Date), the sum of the columns that should be summed togheter, and to get the total add togheter the 3 brom columns.

Most part of the job can be done from the report widarz, i've made a little example with a table of my database.
In the row groups you will set the EmpName instead of the SeriesId
In the value box You'll have Max(Date) and SUM(BROMxxx).

At this point the result of the report will be one line for each employee.

[image]

Next step is to manually add the column total, where you have to add an expression that should look something like this, I don't know how your dataset is called on the report you have to change **"dataset"** with the name of your dataset

[image]

This should solve your problem